# Is it possible to list our all the string variable names and values out

Tags: c#, reflection, field

Is is possible to list our the variable names from the instance and it value.

```
  public class Car
  {
    public string Color;
    public string Model;
    public string Made;
  }

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

//Create new instance
    Car MyCar = new Car();
    MyCar.Color = "Red";
    MyCar.Model = "NISSAN";
    MyCar.Made = "Japan";

//SOMETHING HERE
    foreach (MyCar Variable in MyCar)
    {
      Response.Write("<br/>Variable Name"+  "XXX"+ "Variable Value");
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that using public fields is usually a bad practice. You should be using properties instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
using System;

class Car
{
    public string Color;
    public string Model;
    public string Made;
}

class Example
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var car = new Car
        {
            Color = "Red",
            Model = "NISSAN",
            Made = "Japan"
        };

        foreach (var field in typeof(Car).GetFields())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", field.Name, field.GetValue(car));
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You will need Reflection to do it.
Here you can see a similar question: [How do I get a list of all the public variables I have in a Class? (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295546/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-public-variables-i-have-in-a-class-c).

Based on it, I think your case will be solved by this code:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FieldInfo[] myFieldInfo;
    Type myType = typeof(Car);

    myFieldInfo = myType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

    string result = @"The String fields of Car class are:";

    for (int i = 0; i < myFieldInfo.Length; i++)
    {
        if (myFieldInfo[i].FieldType == typeof(String))
        {
            result += "\r\n" + myFieldInfo[i].Name;
        }
    }

    MessageBox.Show(result);
}

public class Car
{
    public string Color;
    public string Model;
    public string Made;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using reflection. But if you want to enumerate whatever is contained within your class, you could simply use a dictionary and enumerate that.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
foreach (var prop in typeof(Car).GetProperties())
{
  Response.Write(prop.Name + ": " + prop.GetValue(MyCar, null) ?? "(null)");
}
```

Comment: Then it should be `GetFields()` instead of `GetProperties()`, that should work.